# AngularJS ng-show with fade animation

Tags: angularjs, animation, ng-animate, ng-show

I'm new to ngAnimate and I'm trying to accomplish something really simple.

Show div1 and hide div2 when a button is clicked (I managed to do that). And display a fade animation when a div leaves/shows (I didn't manage to do that)

And I don't want to show both divs at the same time when it leaves/shows.

**I prepared a [JSFIDDLE](https://jsfiddle.net/zzvgpv3d/)**

Here is the code

**HTML**

```
    <body ng-controller="AniCtrl as test" >
<div ng-app="app" ng-init="visibleDiv='div1'">

    <md-button ng-click="visibleDiv='div1';test.showBoxOne = !test.showBoxOne">Div 1</md-button>
    <md-button ng-click="visibleDiv='div2';test.showBoxOne = !test.showBoxOne">Div 2</md-button>

  <section>
    <div ng-show="visibleDiv == 'div1'" flex>
     <div class="box" ng-show="test.showBoxOne">
          <p>This is Div 1</p>
     </div>
    </div>
    <div ng-show="visibleDiv == 'div2'" id="div2" flex>
     <div class="box" ng-show="test.showBoxOne">
          <p>This is Div 2</p>
          </div>

    </div>
  </section>
</div>
</body>
```

**JS**

```
   angular.module('app', ['ngMaterial', "ngAnimate"]);

app.controller('AniCtrl', AniCtrl);

function AniCtrl() {
  var self = this;

  self.showBoxOne = false;
  self.showBoxTwo = false;


}
```

**CSS**

```
    .box{
  background-color:black;
  color:white;
  border:1px solid red;
}

.box-one {
  -webkit-transition:all linear 0.5s;
  transition:all linear 0.5s;
}

.box-one.ng-hide {
  opacity:0;
  /* transform: scale(0.8); */
}
```

Thank you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think this should be the solution.

Because we are using `ng-show` we should include the appropriate CSS. Also you cant have the same condition for both divs, so one of the `ng-show` will be

```
<div class="box fade" ng-show="!test.showBoxOne">
          <p>This is Div 2</p>
          </div>

    </div>
```

<kbd>**JSFiddle Demo**</kbd>

**HTML:**

```
<div ng-app="sandbox" ng-init="visibleDiv='div1';test.showBoxOne=true;">
  <div layout="row" flex layout-align="center">
    <md-button ng-click="visibleDiv='div1';test.showBoxOne = !test.showBoxOne">Div 1</md-button>
    <md-button ng-click="visibleDiv='div2';test.showBoxOne = !test.showBoxOne">Div 2</md-button>
  </div>
  <section layout="row">
    <div class="" ng-show="visibleDiv == 'div1'" flex>
     <div class="box fade" ng-show="test.showBoxOne">
          <p>This is Div 1</p>
     </div>
    </div>
    <div class="" ng-show="visibleDiv == 'div2'" id="div2" flex>
     <div class="box fade" ng-show="!test.showBoxOne">
          <p>This is Div 2</p>
          </div>

    </div>
  </section>
</div>
```

**CSS:**

```
.box{
  background-color:black;
  color:white;
  border:1px solid red;
}
.fade {
    transition: all linear 1s;
    opacity: 1;
}

.fade.ng-hide {
    opacity: 0;
}
.ng-hide {
    opacity: 0;
    transition: none 0;
}
```

I hope this solves your issue!

Comment: Thanks so much, it works just as I wanted it. 
I didn't know you had to use css for ng-hide, that's useful-

Comment: EDIT: I just noticed, that the ng-init it's not working. I want to show first without the need to click, div1 
Do you know why?

Comment: @DPF The variable `test.showBoxOne` was not initialized! can you recheck my answer?

Answer (score 0):

In your code

```
 <div class="box" ng-show="test.showBoxOne">
```

You have not given box-one class to the div, in which you have applied animation

```
.box-one.ng-hide {
    opacity:0;
    /* transform: scale(0.8); */
}
```

Correct it as:

```
     <div class="box box-one" ng-show="!test.showBoxOne">
```

This is the updated fiddle **<kbd>[Your FIDDLE](https://jsfiddle.net/varunsukheja/5q56ufgb/)</kbd>**